# Determine whether the series converges or diverges without the use of an Integral test

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Determine whether the series $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(\ln{k})(\ln{(\ln{k}}))}$ converges or diverges without the use of an integral test. I know that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k\ln{k}}$ diverges and that $k(\ln{k})(\ln{\ln{k}})\geq k\ln{k}$ when $k\geq e^e$. However, showing the reciprocal does not prove anything. Can anybody aid me in possibly another way of showing it is convergent or divergent?

Comment: Do you know about the Cauchy condensation test?